# MySQL / JDBC how do you retrieve full terminal view of a query (Showing tables with +-)

Tags: mysql, jdbc

How do you retrieve the terminal view of a mysql select query?

Desired Result: below ; how do I get that in my result set? as opposed to just the numbers for specific columns?

```
+---------+----------+
| Dog_ID  | Owner_ID |
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    |
|    2    |     1    |
|    3    |     2    |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Do you mean all the -, +, and | characters?  Can't be done, except by you.

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant. Very disappointed to find this out

Comment: Why on earth would you want that?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses that exact output in the Console. Open the `MySQL Command Line Client` that comes with MySQL installation and type your select like

```
select * from your_table;
```

Then copy the result out of the console output.